# Stuck on Calculus problem (over 50 attempts)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, computer-science

[image]

So I have half of the question right. I'm pretty sure the expression $3.14$ tends to $\frac{f(x)-f(\pi)}{x-\pi}$
but the stupid webwork says it is wrong. For the final answer I got $y=0.22x - 1.09$, also wrong. I've spent $4$ days on this and I've given up so an answer will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously $\pi\neq 3.14$

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I think it is most likely due to the formatting of the text that is accepted by the web. Does the web accept answer like pi (directly input, instead of giving the first few decimals). For the line equation, I check with graphing device, maybe again due to the formatting?

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(\pi)=\lim_{x \rightarrow\pi}\frac{f(x)-f(\pi)}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x \rightarrow\pi}\frac{\frac{5}{3\pi-7x}+\frac{5}{4\pi}}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x \rightarrow\pi}\frac{20\pi+15\pi-35x}{4\pi(3\pi-7x)(x-\pi)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow\pi}\frac{-35}{4\pi(3\pi-7x)}=\frac{-35}{4\pi(-4\pi)}=\frac{35}{16\pi^2},$$ which is around $0.2216$, as you already wrote.

Then, the tangent equation is:

$$y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0), \text{where}\ x_0=\pi,y_0=f(x_0)=\frac{-5}{4\pi};$$
$$y+\frac{5}{4\pi}=\frac{35}{16\pi^2}(x-\pi);$$
$$y=-\frac{5}{4\pi}+\frac{35}{16\pi^2}x-\frac{35}{16\pi};$$
$$y=\frac{35}{16\pi^2}x-\frac{55}{16\pi}.$$
$$y\approx0.2216x-1.0942.$$

You are correct, but as others mentioned in the comments, it is very likely that the platform requires a specific input format of the answers, (i.e. the precision of the numbers like $\pi$).

Comment: But what expression does pi tend to?

Comment: $\pi$ is just a constant, there is no expression for it. The task is about finding the derivative at point $x_0=\pi.$ The main problem is which expression should be written in the first red box (this is how the platform is built), there are many possibilities (just see my answer, how many $=$ signs are there!) I think you should discuss this with your instructor/teacher. Good luck!